# VBA error 1004 - Runtime

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having a little 'error 1004' with my project and I can't find a way to correct it "properly".

I get an error when I use this code :

```
If Total_account = "OUI" Or (Total_account = "NON" And Range(Cfin).Row = "2") Then GoTo fin
```

I am getting the error when the first condition is met:

```
If Total_account = "OUI"
```

When I have Total_account = "NON" and Range(Cfin).Row = 2, no error.

The only way to fix I found was to do it like that, but it does not look good :

```
If Total_account = "OUI" Then GoTo fin
If (Total_account = "NON" And Range(Cfin).Row = "2") Then GoTo fin
```

I also read the Microsoft support for this error but I don't get it : https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/963259/runtime-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed

Could you help me understand/ find a way to correct this?
The error screenshot is attached to my post.

Thanks in advance !

Jean

[image]

Comment: How have you defined `CFin`? (as well as your other variables)?  And what are their data types?  Also, although VBA may interpret it correctly, the `Row` property returns a `Long`, and you are looking for a `String`.

Comment: You need to post all the code in the sub!

Comment: I suspect `CFin` has a zero or empty value at run-time, and therefore the `Range(cfin)` will raise a 1004 error.

Comment: Cfin is defined as string. Do you think it's the problem? What I do not understand is that this part works... It's the first possibility that crashes.

Comment: What value of `cfin`?

Comment: CFin represents the last cell of a range --> i.e. : $A$2

Comment: Your work-around suggests that your error has to do with the way VBA evaluates logical expressions. In VBA, the entire expression is evaluated even if the answer could be determined early. So, even if Total_Account = "OUI" evaluates to True, the other parts of the expression are still evaluated.

Comment: I don't need an "i.e.", I need a precise value. What value is `cfin` *when the error occurs*?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say `If Total_account = "OUI"` errors?

Comment: @David : Value of Cfin is $C$2

Comment: @SJR : If you take the code I'm having an error with, When Total_Account = "OUI" is TRUE, I get an error. On the other side, if Total_account = "NON" is TRUE And Range(Cfin).Row = "2" is TRUE, I don't get an error.

Comment: OK. When you press the *Debogage* button, can you place the query `?Range(cfin).Row` in the Immediate pane and attempt to evaluate that part?

Comment: I think you need to provide more code, as well as example data necessary to run the procedure. From what you describe, there is no possible error in your code, the range is valid, and there is not a short-circuit problem with the boolean expression.

Comment: Please can you just post all your code because otherwise we're all somewhat in the dark?

Comment: I got my problem. Wrong definition of Cfin... -__- @David, I used your code and I get (translated) "Compilation error, incorrect method or inapropriate object". Actually, posting the code would've been hard because I'm Calling different macros. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Perhaps your computer does not like shorthand `CFin$` instead using `CFin As String` and `Total_account As String`. In any case, wrong definition of `CFin` would cause that error for reason I mentioned in my answer. If `CFin` isn't a valid range *Address* or identifier, then the 1004 error is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a standard module in a new workbook. I guarantee it cannot cause an error, no matter what value you have for `Total_account`.

```
Sub foo()
Dim Total_account as String
Dim CFin as String
CFin = "$C$2"
Total_account = "OUI"

If Total_account = "OUI" Or (Total_account = "NON" And Range(CFin).Row = "2") Then GoTo fin

fin:
End Sub
```

This suggest a problem elsewhere in your code. Judging from the 1004 message, if the error raises on your boolean expression, this can only be because `CFin` is unassigned (empty string, empty/zero numeric value).

If `CFin` has a zero or empty value at run-time, therefore the `Range(cfin)` will raise a 1004 error, since `Range("").Row` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to put workSheet.Range(Cfin).Row instead of Range(Cfin).Row as Perhaps your code is behind Sheet1, so when you change the focus to Sheet2 the objects cannot be found issue will happen.

Please try below code.

```
Sub your_sub

Dim workSheet As Worksheet
Set workSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'guessing your looking at Sheet1

Dim Cfin As String
Cfin = "$C$2"


If Total_account = "OUI" Or (Total_account = "NON" And workSheet.(Cfin).Row = "2") Then GoTo fin

MsgBox "no" 'your code

fin:

MsgBox "yes" ' your code

End Sub
```